# Reading a JSON file from web page and convert it in List<Object> in C#

Tags: c#, php, json

I'm facing some problems with the read of a JSON file, which is this one:

```
{
  "giocatori": [
    {
      "Giocatore": "124",
      "Cognome": "DE SANCTIS",
      "Ruolo": "P",
      "Squadra": "ROM"
    },
    {
      "Giocatore": "140",
      "Cognome": "MIRANTE",
      "Ruolo": "P",
      "Squadra": "PAR"
    },
    {
      "Giocatore": "156",
      "Cognome": "SKORUPSKI",
      "Ruolo": "P",
      "Squadra": "ROM"
    }
  ],
  "success": 1
}
```

What I want to get from this PHP is an List, where the Player's class with this attributes;

```
public string Giocatore;
public string Cognome;
public string Ruolo;
public string Squadra;
```

I don't know why, but I face some problems with the Microsoft.Json library, in particular with Json.DeserializeObject> method, which is not able to read that web page. Can you provide some hint how to obtain a List in C# of Player ? Thank you so much for your support !

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the serializer you are using?  Is it [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or something else?

Comment: What exception is being thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to http://json2csharp.com/, post your JSON there, and get the following classes:

```
public class Giocatori
{
    public string Giocatore { get; set; }
    public string Cognome { get; set; }
    public string Ruolo { get; set; }
    public string Squadra { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Giocatori> giocatori { get; set; }
    public int success { get; set; }
}
```

To deserialize your JSON string with [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), do:

```
var root = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonString);
var list = root.giocatori;
```

To deserialize your JSON string with [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), a widely used, free, open source JSON serializer, download and install it according to the instructions on the [home page](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and do:

```
var root = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
var list = root.giocatori;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I was just one line of code away from the correct solution ! Now I can read an easy way the data. Now I have to work for the rest of the program !

Comment: Now I want to use these value in a Windows Phone Application. How Can I deal with the async method ? It seems that Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString); isn't recognize. Thank

Comment: @Ilovecoding - I'm a desktop developer so I'm not sure, suggest asking another question.  Maybe try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726970/why-have-warning-newtonsoft-json-jsonconvert-deserializeobjectasync